# RegEx Reverse in real time

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing a txt.replace on a user entered field. I want to only allow certain characters and the function will replace them in real time as the user types. The code I have is

```
txt.value = txt.value.replace(/^[ A-Za-z0-9_\-.]*$/i, '');
```

But that matches the characters I want and replaces them not the characters I don't want. I tried using an opposite match as suggested elsewhere

```
txt.value = txt.value.replace(/^(!? A-Za-z0-9_\-.)*$/i, '');
```

But that still didn't seem to work. How do I take that RegEx and replace anything that doesn't match that formula with `''`

Comment: Do not use `^` and `$` because you replace only when full string match to the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global flag (`g`) **is needed** because a key can be held down, generating multiple instances of the character, and the `keyup` event will only fire **once**.

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^ \w-.]/g, '')" />
```

https://regex101.com/r/Nv3U1w/2/tests explains the regular expression and contains test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use negated character class

```
/[^ \w.-]+/
```

Code:

```
txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^ \w.-]+/, '');
```

`\w` matches alphanumeric characters and `_`(underscore).

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^ \w.-]/, '')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you would have to use

```
txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^ a-z0-9_\-.]+/gi, '');
```

This would match all characters not in the character class [^ A-Za-z0-9_-.]

> Note /regex/g ensures that all matches are replaced and not just one

Comment: You don't need both uppercase & lowercase range when using `i` flag. `g` is also not required as OP is replacing on each key press.